# how to maintain progress bar in android?

Tags: android, listview, progress-bar

want to create listview with 2 component in every row 1st progressbar and 2nd Button that display a current value of progressbar.

for that i m using custom list view the problem is that when i scroll the listview the progressbar cant maintain it's previous state.

Please help me out to solve this problem.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: show some code so the other users can help figure out what's going on.

Comment: Since listView reuses the views for efficiency that's why progressbar state will not be maintained.You have to use implement some logic
inside getView mehtod of custom adapter if you post your custom adapter code i can help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do that by using following logic.

1 create one arraylist for example.

```
`public ArrayList<integer> progValue = new ArrayList<integer>();`
```

2  now in custom list adapter class constructor initialize progvalue with value "0" as following

> for(int i = 0; i < yourLIst.size(); i++) {
>                progValue.add(i,0);
>   }

3   now in the progress bar change listener change the value of progValue object as per your progress bar value like

> progValue.add(i,p_value)

4 finally set that value in your in  getView  method. like

> progObject.setProgress(progValue.get(pos));

That's all.

change the code as per your requirement i have put just for example.

Comment: Thanks...But how to get progObject in my Thread that exist in adapter?    Thread change progress value...

Comment: girish ask clearly i m clarify what u ask? and why u need thread?

Comment: No i have custom Progressbar...that shows progress of playing media